# extract meta data from Stripe web hook .Net

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm struggling to work with the data posted by Stripe to my web hook.

I'm using the basic checkout. I have everything working as intended. CLI is forwarding the web hooks after "checkout.session.completed". My hook is being hit as expected. However, I can't work out how to extract the meta data. I can see it in the object but I can't work out how. What is an "IhasObject"?  I copied the code from the docs below.

```
 var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        try
        {
            // check if was from Stripe
            var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], endpointSecret);

            // Handle the event
            if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted)
            {
                // TODO update the DB and set the booking to PAID based on the transaction Id 
                // in Metadata
                var session = stripeEvent.Data.Object;
```

I can see the correct data in the session object in VS debug and in the raw json. But how do I get it out of the session object or event?  It's unclear and there are no examples in the documentation.  I am tempted to read the json into a POCO but isn't this the point of the event object?

Can someone point me in the right direction? I just want to fulfill the order but the examples don't show how to work with the session object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast the payload of the event to a CheckoutSession and read the metadata.

```
 var session = (Stripe.Checkout.Session) stripeEvent.Data.Object; 
 var metadata = session.Metadata;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It would have been helpful had this been included in the examples. I already had a razor page called Checkout which confused the issue because Checkout.Session was not recognised. When I did this it worked.   "as Stripe.Checkout.Session;" I will rename my Checkout page.

Comment: hmm, actually that wasn't the issue. Looks like you have to do "Stripe.Checkout.Session" otherwise it doens't work so the examples are wrong.